# Is QStackedWidget is the recommended way to handle multiple windows in Qt Program?

Tags: c++, qt

I build `Qt` gui and have many windows to handle with.
I implement this meanwhile with `QStackedWidget`s (replace the window in buttons click signal), but I am not sure this is the right way.

Can I maintain a lot of windows in this technique ?

what is the prefered way / best practice ?

This is piece of my code (relevant):

```
ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(new Menu);
ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(new Repetitive);
ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(new SinglePulse);


void MainWindow::on_btnSinglePulse_clicked()
{
  ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
}

void MainWindow::on_btnMenu_clicked()
{
  ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_btnPulseGroup_clicked()
{
  ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fine, but maybe you could simplify your code if you create only one slot, and check the `sender()` in that.

```
void onButtonClicked()
{
    if ( sender() == ui->button0 )
    {
        ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex( 0 );
    }
    else if ( sender() == ui->button1 )
    {
        ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex( 1 );
    }
    // ... and so on.
}
```

Or you could just simply use a `QTabWidget`.