# Handling multiple windows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I use `QStackedWidget` to handle multiple windows/forms in a Qt application
according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328473/is-qstackedwidget-is-the-recomendded-way-to-handle-multiple-windows-in-qt-progra).

I use this pattern:

1. Add all widget objects to the `QStackedWidget` in mainwindow.cpp
2. Get signal from sub-window on request to change window
3. mainwindow replaces the window (it updates the QStackedWidget in the right slot)

**My question :**

is this the right way to do this? I have a lot of windows in my applications and want to ensure this is the common best practice.
This pattern means that i have pointers to all of the windows in my main window.

piece of my code:
mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

   ui->setupUi(this);

   mnuWin = new Menu();
   singlePulseWin = new SinglePulse();
   repetitive = new Repetitive();
   treatmentType = new TreatmentType();
   //... and so on ....

   connect(mnuWin,&Menu::updateMainWindowStackWidget,this,&MainWindow::onChangeWindowRequested);
   connect(singlePulseWin,&SinglePulse::updateMainWindowStackWidget,this,&MainWindow::onChangeWindowRequested); 
   connect(repetitive,&Repetitive::updateMainWindowStackWidget,this,&MainWindow::onChangeWindowRequested);
   connect(treatmentType,&TreatmentType::updateMainWindowStackWidget,this,&MainWindow::onChangeWindowRequested);
   //... and so on ....

   ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(mnuWin);
   ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(singlePulseWin);
   ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(repetitive);
   ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(treatmentType);
   //... and so on ....

   ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}   

void MainWindow::onChangeWindowRequested(int ind)  //slot
{
    ui->pagesWidget->setCurrentIndex(ind);
}
```

menu.cpp :

```
void Menu::on_btnMenuSinglePulse_clicked()
{
   emit updateMainWindowStackWidget(1);
}

void Menu::on_btnMenuRepetitive_clicked()
{
   emit updateMainWindowStackWidget(2);
}

void Menu::on_btnMenuBurst_clicked()
{
   emit updateMainWindowStackWidget(3);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Depends on what you need. If only one "window" should be visible at a time it sounds like a good approach. If you need more than one windows visibale at a time this is not the way to go.

Comment: Have you looked at [`QTabWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html)?

Comment: Another thing you could do is create a helper method, called something like `addForm(mnuWin, ...);`, which you then call for each form page, and which then does the necessary connects and `ui->pagesWidget->addWidget(..)` and so on, whatever is necessary. This will prevent copy-paste bugs and short your code too.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I cant use more than one window because i use qt embedded and eglfs plugin that require just one window. forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QStackedWidget is a good way to deal with Multi-window .why not put the buttons in the mainWindow ,so that you can change the pagesWidget's currentWidget more convenient instead of create signal-slot