# Application with multiple windows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

What is a good way to create application with multiple windows in Qt? Something like GIMP. I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511292/handling-multiple-windows-in-qt) answer and it is not what I need.

I have two windows, one with controls and one with OpenGL inside. Right now I have something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // some code

    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();

    GLWindow gw;
    gw.show();

    // ...
}
```

I don't like this for two reasons. First reason is when I start my application, window with OpenGL will be on top (because it is last to call `show()`) but `MainWindow` will be buried somewhere under all opened windows. What I need is both windows in front of everything (like GIMP), preferably with focus on `MainWindow` (I guess I can bring them to front, so that is minor issue). Second reason I don't like this is that my application will be closed completely only when I close both windows.

So I was thinking of having a reference to `GLWindow` inside `MainWindow`, and creating it **from** `MainWindow`.

Would that be a good way to create application with several windows?

EDIT: GLWindow inherits from QOpenGLWindow.

Comment: Are you planning to share the controls window with multiple opengl views or a single one?

Comment: @Damien LEFEVRE Single one.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would choose a secondary QMainWindow over a floating dialog (non-modal)? .I'm not quite sure what you need to achieve so it's hard to advise :) but if possible I'd use that. Give the main window as parent for the dialog which would insure it would be on top.

Comment: It is not a secondary QMainWindow, this class GLWindow inherits from QOpenGLWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right, but with the following simple tricks, you can resolve both issues that cause you do not like your right method:

1. To activate both windows, just do as follows:

```
    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();
    mw.activateWindow();

    GLWindow gw;
    gw.show();
    gw.activateWindow();
```

2. To resolve the quit problem, you have to override the `closeEvent` in both windows. To do that, add the following code into the **header** file of your both windows:

```
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;
```

and in the implementation of the closeEvent, just write `qApp->quit();`. This way once you close either window, your application will terminate completely.

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    qApp->quit();
}
```

and

**GLWindow.cpp**

```
void GLWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    qApp->quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the situation but, typically, you can make the 'secondary' widgets child [dialogs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) of the `QMainWindow`.  Given your example code that would be something like...

```
int main ()
{
    // some code

    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();

    /*
     * Secondary windows should be created with the QMainWindow mw
     * as their parent.
     */
    GLWindow gw(&mw);

    /*
     * Set the Qt::Dlaog window flag to `encourage' the QMainWindow
     * and its children to behave as a group.
     */
    gw.setWindowFlags(gw.windowFlags() | Qt::Dialog);
    gw.show();

    // ...
}
```

Now all widgets behave as a group (possibly subject to the window manager being used) and closing the `QMainWindow` will, by default, close the application.

Comment: I have added edit to my question. GLWindow inherits from QOpenGLWindow. This is where stuff regarding OpenGL happens. Other window is QMainWindow and there are controls. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @dosvarog I don't understand how that changes anything.

Comment: You said that you don't completely understand the situation, so I thought this would clarify it. GLWindow inherits from QOpenGLWindow, so it is of type QWindow. Main window is of type QMainWindow. So, I have two windows that should act as one application. I will try with your advice to "hint" at GLWindow with this flag.